# For Azure DocumentDB input binding, Is there a way to get the document id from the headers?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-functions

I am trying to use Azure function to automate a process, where by a third party send me a http request with document id in the http header. I want to use that id to use documentdb input binding.

I have already learnt that we can do it from the body. Thanks to Brett Samblanet for replying on the Azure documentation itself.

Alternatively I can redirect it further by putting "document id" into the query string, that will be bit inefficient but still better than not being able to use it at all. So it will be great If anybody can please help me to find out a way to:

- use http header as document id.
- use query string as document id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment you can only bind to values from the request body. We have a PR already merged that expands this to allow binding to the query string as well. But this change is not currently in production (I can update this response when it is): https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/pull/568

There is currently no support for headers but I've filed an issue: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/591

FYI -- I also copied this answer here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/functions-bindings-documentdb/